# "Illegal offset" inside of loop

Tags: php, mysql, email, loops, while-loop

The following code produces an illegal offset error every time the `while()` loops:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'username' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/admin/scripts/email_owners_send.php on line 48

I'm trying to set `$name` to be `$email['username']` if `$email['username']` **isn't empty**, and if **is** empty, `$name` should be set to `$email`. `$email` is set by the `while()` statement, from a `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. This is my code at the moment:

```
// print out all the email address recipients
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ownersemails WHERE deleted=0 LIMIT 5");
$recipients = '';
$total = mysql_num_rows($query);
$num = 0;
while($email = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // add to count
    $num++;

    // set email
    $email = $email['email'];

    // set name as username if apparant
    if(!empty($email['username'])) {
        $name = $email;
    }
    else {
        $name = $email['username'];
    }

    // add to recipients string (=. append)
    $recipients .= '{ "email": "'.$email.'", "name": "'.$name.'" }';
    // only add a comma if it isn't the last one
    if($num!=$total) {
        $recipients .=',';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the $email variable set by the while loop

```
 while($email = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```

then here you are overwriting it:

```
$email = $email['email'];
```

so `$email` will become a string and not an array. You could change this to

```
$email_address = $email['email']
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array named `$email` which holds all the columns in your database row. And you are overwriting that object with the value of only  the email column:

```
while($email = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // add to count
    $num++;

    // set email
    $email = $email['email'];
...
```

Don't do that.  It would make a lot more sense to call the row object `$row`. You should name variables so that its obvious what they are.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // add to count
    $num++;

    // set email
    $email = $row['email'];
...
```